# Where can I find Honeycomb back button in Android folder?

Tags: android, android-image, android-icons

I would like to know where can I find the back button image, the one used by the android tablet emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the images which are used by the android platform are placed in the **drawable** folder under the **res** directory.

1.Open the android root directory(Installed directory).

2.Navigate to the res directory.**E:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-12\data\res**

Comment: Thanks, I found a lot of interresting Icons there. But i didn't manage to found the one i was looking for, the "back button" icon. Do you know where can i find it?

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in the android.jar file in your sdk folder.

For example mine is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar (for SDK version 8, to get a different version the change the "android-8" part of the path)

You can extract the .jar using winzip/7z etc as it is just a zip file in disguise. You will then find the drawables folder in the folders you unzipped.